# Webpack multi compiler mode

Tags: webpack

I have 3 different config files,
I am running these configs in multi compiler mode.

The problem starts when i am trying to deploy all the assets to s3 **After** all of the compiler instances has finished.
Is there any webpack way to do ?

```
module.exports = [
    merge(baseConfig, mainConfig),
    merge(baseConfig,secondConfig),
    merge(baseConfig,thirdCareConfig),
];

on done deploy to s3 using webpack-s3-plugin
```